# Hibernate 4.1.11 hql delete query with where in list

Tags: hibernate, hql, hql-delete

I want to delete from a table some entries with specific ids. I want to know the syntax of this request

```
delete from table where id in list_of_ids
```

in hql.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the id of your table is of type Long, the correct way to perform the delete is as follows:

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
ids.add(1L);
ids.add(2L);

Query q = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM YourEntityName ye WHERE ye.id IN (:list)");

q.setParameterList("list", ids);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `delete from Table as table where id="value"`

In above case

**Table**- Pojo class

**table**- Database table name

---

Comment: thanks but i dont have a single value i have a list of ids i want to delete all table with id in this list of ids

Comment: So you are have more than one id , wherever it occur you need to delete the entire record right

Comment: yes i want the equivalent in hql of this " delete from table where id IN (...) "

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Query qry = session.createQuery(delete from Pojo where pojo.property in (:bindParameter);
qry.setParameter("bindParameter", list);
```

Note this statement SQL exception if list is empty.